# Tomcat with HTTPS (server not response)

Tags: ubuntu, https, tomcat8

I need to use `HTTPS` in tomcat. I followed the official documentation on the apache website but it is not working. This is my config in `server.xml`:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
        keystoreFile="~/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
        disableUploadTimeout="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

this is the result I get when I try to connect with http:

```
curl -IL http://localhost:8080
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 11 Jul 2016 07:03:04 GMT
```

with https:

```
curl -IL https://localhost:8443
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

can you help me?? I can't see what is wrong.

Comment: Where is this hosted?

Answer (score 0):

Change the server.xml to following restart tomcat and then try.

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
        keystoreFile="~/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
        disableUploadTimeout="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```